# How to view jars being used/accessed by Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jar

I need to clean a web application and remove the unused jars. The problem is I'm not familiar with the web application. Is there a way to check the list of jars being used/accessed by `Tomcat`?

I tried to used `Window's Process Explorer` to view the jars being accessed by `javaw.exe` but it seems that Tomcat loads all the jars regardless if its being used or not once the web application is accessed. Is it possible to set `Tomcat` to load jars only if they're needed?

The web application is relatively new and is not yet on production so it's best if we could clean it while it's still early.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this problem independent of Tomcat since it seems that you're mainly interested in your web application's dependencies. While there are a number of tools to analyze JAR dependencies I recommend [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) from JBoss. It provides a well-organized report that provides a number of insights into an application. Check out the [sample report](http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/examples/jbossas7/index.html) to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to have what I'm looking for but I still need to test it. I have no background with JBoss. The web application I'm running host jars from J2ee, Spring, etc. Currently, I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat only to run my project. If I'm not mistaken, JBoss is a server right? Do you happen to know which Jboss [`Web Profile Only (Java EE6 Certified)`, `Everything (NOT Java EE6 Certified)`, `Quickstarts`] is most similar to Tomcat 7.0?

Comment: JBoss.org has a number of projects, including an application server, but in this case I'm referring to a project called Tattletale. Here is the usage info from their documentation: 

Running
Tattletale recursive scans the specified directory for Java archives and generates the reports in the specified directory or in the current directory.

java -jar tattletale.jar [-exclude=<excludes>] <input-directory> <output-directory>

Example
java -Xmx512m -jar tattletale.jar ~/myjavaproject/mydistribution output

Comment: Sigh. I forgot that comments don't include formatting. Essentially you just need to download a JAR file from the site then run a command like "java -Xmx512m -jar tattletale.jar ~/myjavaproject/mydistribution output"

Comment: Is Tattletale not a JBoss tool? Does it mean that I can run it independently regardless what my server is? You can mark a code in comment by using a ` . :D Thanks again!

Comment: It's an independent tool that doesn't depend on any particular application server. You can run it against any Java project -- it doesn't have to be a web application.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I will try it out. :D Hopefully, it works. I'm using Spring jars so I'm not sure if it can also detect the Spring jars. Will post again here if I was able to test it and it works. :D

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't seem to produce an accurate report since some of the used jars were marked as unused. However, in general Tattletale is good and I think it will do since I have knowledge on some of the functions of the jars. The other reports are also great. :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've looked at [Tomcat classloading](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) but I remember we used to mess around with the log4j debug levels to get an idea of what was loaded and when.

[This article](http://muzso.hu/2009/03/17/debugging-tomcat-class-loading-issues) gives a nice overview of how he does it (albeit with an older version of Tomcat). It should give you some ideas on what to look for.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I will check it out. If you also know some tool which can do it. Please feel free to comment here.